# MongoDB Command failed with error 91(shutDownInProgress)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, replicaset, mongodb-authentication

We have mongo cluster which is a `3 node` replicaset and we connect the cluster using Spring boot app. This cluster have a daily maintenance window of `20-30 sec` during which one of the node goes down and it automatically comes up post that greenzone.

We are using Mongodb java sync driver(Spring-data-mongodb) of version `4.6.1` and MongoDB cluster is having version - `5.0.14`.

In the logs, I could see it continously logs the error "`Exception in monitor thread - Command failed with error 91 - The server is in Quiesce mode and will shutdown`" for around 1000 times during this period (~30 sec). And after that it automatically connects back with the log - "`Monitor thread successfully connected`".

My Query is:

1. How to avoid logging these many redundant exception from our app as it's difficult to monitor the useful logs
2. Why the app tries to connect so frequently, is there any way to increase the retry attempt time so that it improves the logging
3. In the error it says "Command failed", what exactly the command is which it tries to execute during the greenzone so frequently(`~30/sec`). It's not coming from our App as we don't have any health check monitor in built.
4. Does this failure counts comes under Login failure attempt?